# How to Grab All of Left Joined Data and Filter Data in One Doctrine Query?

Tags: php, sql, symfony1, doctrine

I want to be able to narrow my blog posts to posts that contain a certain tag. But, for each blog post that contains the specific tag, I want to grab *all* of the tags in the same query. So, using this query:

```
BlogTable::getInstance()
    ->createQuery()
    ->select('b.*, t.*')
    ->from('Blog b')
    ->leftJoin('b.Tags t')
    ->where('t.content = ?', $tag)
    ->execute()
```

will only join the tags that equal the specified tag, which results in extra queries for lazy loading the tags when needed.

How do I narrow the blog posts by tag, but at the same time grab all of the tags for the post in one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want two inner joins, one to ensure the specific tag exists (t1 in my sample) and one to return all existing tags (t2 in my sample).

```
BlogTable::getInstance()
    ->createQuery()
    ->select('b.*, t2.*')
    ->from('Blog b')
    ->InnerJoin('b.Tags t1')
    ->InnerJoin('b.Tags t2')
    ->where('t1.content = ?', $tag)
    ->execute()
```